# Invalid switch [$(args[rvtFile].path)]. Variables that expand to paths must be quoted

Tags: autodesk-forge

Hi Autodesk Forge team,

I have issue with [create activity](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/step5-publish-activity/) need help with Design Automation. This is body I'm tried to achive with a activity to extract room data, but have some wrong with command line. I don't know what is extract issue i'm faceing. I guess it have some update from server but don't know how to modify a update to fix that.

This is body input :

```
{
    "id": "{{activityName}}",
    "commandLine": [ "$(engine.path)\\\\revitcoreconsole.exe /i $(args[rvtFile].path) /al $(appbundles[{{appBudleName}}].path)" ],
    "parameters": {
      "rvtFile": {
        "zip": false,
        "ondemand": false,
        "verb": "get",
        "description": "Input Revit model",
        "required": true
      },
      "result": {
        "zip": false,
        "ondemand": false,
        "verb": "put",
        "description": "Results",
        "required": true,
        "localName": "result.rvt"
      }
    },
    "engine": "Autodesk.Revit+2022",
    "appbundles": [ "{{dasNickName}}.{{appBudleName}}+{{appBundleAlias}}" ],
    "description": "Extract Room from Revit file."
}
```

Output issue :

```
{
    "commandLine": [
        "Invalid switch [$(args[rvtFile].path)]. Variables that expand to paths must be quoted.Invalid switch [$(appbundles[RoomExtractor2].path)]. Variables that expand to paths must be quoted. (Parameter 'commandLine')"
    ]
}
```

Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in this blog post, you'd have to place the `path` variables inside quotes:
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/design-automation-command-line

e.g.

```
{
  "commandLine": [
    "$(engine.path)\InventorCoreConsole.exe /i \"$(args[InventorDoc].path)\" /al \"$(appbundles[SomeApp].path)\" /s \"$(settings[script].path)\""
  ],
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, after 3 hours just look to it and I'm also fixed my issue, this is my modified :

"commandLine": [ "$(engine.path)\\\\revitcoreconsole.exe /i \"$(args[rvtFile].path)\" /al \"$(appbundles[{{appBudleName}}].path)\"" ],